# Obj-C: Disappearing variable

Tags: objective-c, variables, memory-management, uibutton, nsdictionary

I am new to Objective-C and could use some help with a problem that has left me stumped.  I call it the problem of the disappearing variable.  I will attempt to describe it below.

I'm attempting to create my own tab bar controller and view as I've concluded that `UITabBarController` and `UITabBar` don't allow me to do what I need to do (I need to change the appearance of the tab bar quite drastically).

I've subclassed `UIViewController` and `UIView` to create my classes `SYTabBarController` and `SYTabBar`, respectively.

In `SYTabBar`, I've written a method to programmatically add `UIButton`s to my view:

```
- (UIButton*) addButtonWithFrame:(CGRect)frame action:(SEL)action target:(id)target imageToken:(NSString*)imageToken
{
    UIButton *b = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    [b addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIImage
    *unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:APPEND_STRING(@"TBI+Unselected+", @"imageToken")],
    *selectedImage   = [UIImage imageNamed:APPEND_STRING(@"TBI+Selected+", @"imageToken")],
    *selectedBgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TBI+SelectedBG"];

    [b setImage:unselectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [b setImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [b setImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [b setBackgroundImage:selectedBgImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [b setBackgroundImage:selectedBgImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [b setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:NO];
    [b setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO];
    [b setAdjustsImageWhenDisabled:NO];
    [self addSubview:b];

    return b;
}
```

I invoke this method in `SYTabBarController` to create five buttons:

```
    UIButton *button1 = [self.tabBar addButtonWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 45)
                                                 action:@selector(changeView:)
                                                 target:self
                                             imageToken:@"Popular"];

    UIButton *button2 = [self.tabBar addButtonWithFrame:CGRectMake(64, 0, 64, 45)
                                                 action:@selector(changeView:)
                                                 target:self
                                             imageToken:@"Feed"];

    UIButton *button3 = [self.tabBar addButtonWithFrame:CGRectMake(64*2, 0, 64, 45)
                                                 action:@selector(changeView:)
                                                 target:self
                                             imageToken:@"Capture"];

    UIButton *button4 = [self.tabBar addButtonWithFrame:CGRectMake(64*3, 0, 64, 45)
                                                 action:@selector(changeView:)
                                                 target:self
                                             imageToken:@"Likes"];

    UIButton *button5 = [self.tabBar addButtonWithFrame:CGRectMake(64*4, 0, 64, 45)
                                                 action:@selector(changeView:)
                                                 target:self
                                             imageToken:@"Profile"];
```

Then, still in `SYTabBarController`, I try to take these five buttons and add them as keys in a dictionary which is stored as a property (see code below).  The dictionary contains `UIViewController` instances keyed to the buttons.  The idea is that when one of the five buttons is pressed, it will call the selector `changeView:`, which in turn will retrieve the respective `UIViewController` instance from the dictionary and display its view.

```
    self.viewControllersKeyedToButtons = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                                          rootViewController,
                                          button1,

                                          [[SYViewController_Feed alloc] init],
                                          button2,

                                          [[SYViewController_Capture alloc] init],
                                          button3,

                                          [[SYViewController_Likes alloc] init],
                                          button4,

                                          [[SYViewController_Profile alloc] init],
                                          button5,

                                          nil];
```

My code crashes right when I initialize the dictionary.  I get this error message:

> 2012-12-27 02:54:28.498 Smuvy[17931:c07] -[UIButton copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x717fc10
>       2012-12-27 02:54:28.500 Smuvy[17931:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x717fc10'
>       *** First throw call stack:
>       (0x174c012 0x1223e7e 0x17d74bd 0x173bbbc 0x173b94e 0x17ce714 0x1712b55 0x172d5a8 0x65d6 0x2c6e 0x1687b7 0x168da7 0x169fab 0x17b315 0x17c24b 0x16dcf8 0x3676df9 0x3676ad0 0x16c1bf5 0x16c1962 0x16f2bb6 0x16f1f44 0x16f1e1b 0x1697da 0x16b65c 0x2aad 0x29d5)
>       libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
>       (lldb)

Now here's the mystery.  When I track the variable `button5` in my debugger, I notice that right before I try to instantiate the dictionary, it disappears!  No wonder I get an error message.

As I am new to Objective-C (and to C) I don't know much about memory management and I imagine I've done something wrong with my variables.  I've run Instruments and interestingly enough, I see all `UIButton` instances alive and well.  It seems, thus, that the button is there, it's just the pointer that has somehow gone kaput.

Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "it disappears"? From the source code or what? Also, it'd be useful to know what the `APPEND_STRING()` macro does.

Comment: I meant to say that while I was tracking it in my debugger pane, it disappeared from the pane.

Comment: The `APPEND_STRING()` macro is just a shorthand for concatenating two strings:  `#define APPEND_STRING(string1,string2) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", string1, string2]`

Comment: OK: here's the solution I've ultimately adopted:
I've created two `NSArray`s, one for view controllers, another for buttons.  I store the view controllers in the same order as the buttons, so I cross-reference them through their array indexes.  Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an NSDictionary, [it makes copies of the keys that you provide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Dictionaries.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000134-SW8), by calling `-copy`, which calls `-copyWithZone:`.  These methods are part of the [`NSCopying`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSCopying) protocol.

Unfortunately, UIButton does not conform to that protocol. It isn't copyable. When NSDictionary tries to send the `-copy` message to it, an exception is raised, as you have discovered.

Alternatives:

- Use an [`NSMapTable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMapTable_class/Reference/NSMapTable.html) instead.
- Wrap the keys in an NSValue, using [`+[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSValue/valueWithNonretainedObject%3a) or [`+[NSValue valueWithPointer:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSValue/valueWithPointer%3a). (If you're using ARC, NSValue will not ensure that your object is retained, so you will need to make a strong reference to the object some other way.)
- Use some other method to determine a key that the view controller and the UIButton can share. (For instance, have them both refer to the same string.)
- Don't use a map at all. Perhaps keep your view controllers in an array, and use the `tag`  on the UIButton to store the index of the corresponding view controller in the array.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is crystal clear!  It seems the problem was located between the computer and the chair: I didn't quite understand that `NSDictionary` made copies of its keys.  Thanks much for the suggestions.  I will look into `NSMapTable`.  And thanks for the links too, they aid a lot.

Comment: I took a look at `NSMapTable` but, as it it is iOS 6+ only, I've decided to try something else (see [my comment to my question above!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051380/obj-c-disappearing-variable#comment19433943_14051380)).

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors here.

Firstly, in the documentation of NSDictionary, it is stated that its keys must conform to the `<NSCopying>` protocol, i. e. they should respond to `copyWithZone:`, because the keys are copied when they're inserted into the dictionary. (This is true for keys only, the corresponding objects need not be copiable.) The exception occurs because `UIButton` (it's just a subclass of `UIControl` and `UIView`) does not implement this method (if you read the error message, it will be clear).

So you can't use the buttons as keys in the dictionary - if you need an association between buttons and the view controllers (by the way, I suspect a design problem here, this solution seems rather hackish), use separate keys for the buttons and the view controllers, and use for example a simple linear search for finding a view controller for the corresponding button.

Or, if you're not afraid of using CoreFoundation, you can use `CFDictionary` (which is toll-free bridged with `NSDictionary`) and supply an appropriate custom key callback that does not copy the keys.

Comment: the buttons are added to `self.subviews' and will be retained

Comment: Thank you very much!  I will take a look at `CFDictionary`.  I like the linear search idea also, I will look at `NSMapTable` as Kurt suggested as well.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that a message is sent to an object that cannot handle that message. In your case `copyWithZone:` is sent to an instance of a `UIButton`. `copyWithZone:` is a method declared in the `NSCopying` protocol, but that protocol is not adopted by a UIButton.

This specific message is sent, because you're adding an entry to an NSDictionary with a UIButton as key. As stated in the [NSDictionary class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html), a key is copied (using **copyWithZone:**; keys must conform to the NSCopying protocol), and the copy is added to the new dictionary.